# Using Facebook Login safely on an insecure page

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-login

Suppose I have two URLs:
`http://example.com/createinsecureaccount`
`https://example.com/accesssecureaccount`

A possible user flow is as follows:
1.  User visits insecure page and creates an account via FB. My site tells the user they are logged in(*).
2A.  User visits secure page to access account details via FB.
2B.  Man-in-the middle visits secure page and uses credentials stolen during #1 to impersonate the user.

Is there a means for me to differentiate between a login token created on an insecure page and one created on a secure page? My current thinking is that I could use attach a nonce to Facebook's <strike>`redirect_uri`</strike> `state` parameter (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#logindialog ), but I'm unsure if this is reasonable/safe.

(*) This is a half-truth to make the user happy.  The site pretends the user is fully logged in until they attempt to access protected content, at which point they will be asked to login again.  Sites like Amazon have similar behavior.

Comment: Facebook has a reauthentication API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication), but it only works for apps, not web sites.

Comment: Why not have both URLs secure under HTTPS?

Comment: @SilverlightFox: Due to business requirements beyond my control as an engineer.

Comment: What kind of “business requirement” would that be …? Even if users need to be able to call a landing page using HTTP only (_“because marketing said so”_ …?) – can’t you go to an HTTPS URL first when they decide to login using FB, and only call the FB login dialog from there?

Comment: _“but it only works for apps, not web sites”_ – that makes no sense btw. … if you _are_ using Facebook login on an external website, then you _are_ using an app.

Comment: @CBroe: Your alternative proposal is a compromise.  Marketing wants to have a facebook login on insecure pages.  I as an engineer can veto due to security issues, but will only do so if those security issues are unsolvable.  They are *in principle* solvable, but whether the facebook API offers a safe solution I don't know.  As for calling login on an external website an app, fundamental difference is that an app can parse the content of a user-initiated query (i.e., a flow in the form of App->FB Login Page->FB Response page), whereas a website cannot.

Comment: I still don’t know what you mean by that last part, resp. what it has to do with whether asking for re-authentication will work on a website or not.

Comment: @CBroe: The reauthentication API opens a user popup on facebook.com, which then redirects the user to a facebook URI containing the API response.  As a result, websites cannot access the API response, though a desktop app or a browser extension can do so.  Other facebook APIs redirect the user to the originating website (with special query parameters) or are called via can be called client-side, allowing their use for websites.

Comment: Re-authentiction is requested via a call to the normal login dialog endpoint, just with the additional parameter `auth_type` – so you can specify the `redirect_uri` parameter the same way as you would during “normal” login, to have it redirect back to your website. You’ll then get a new `code` parameter to exchange for an access token.